# How to Convert System.Net.MailMessage to RawContent

Tags: c#, imap, mailmessage, openpop

I use IMAP protocol to get Email from Inboxes. Now i need to convert the Result that is a List of MailMessage to RawContent , To convert It to OpenPop.Pop3 Message, But when I use

> var message = new OpenPop.Mime.Message(rawMessage);

if It's content contain Persian content,  for Example in "From" or "To" section of header email if Display Name is "مسعود بهرامی", After convert It to OpenPop Message it convert to "??????????????"

Here's code for Extract RawMessage from MailMessage

```
private const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    private static readonly Type MailWriter = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    private static readonly ConstructorInfo MailWriterConstructor = MailWriter.GetConstructor(Flags, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo CloseMethod = MailWriter.GetMethod("Close", Flags);
    private static readonly MethodInfo SendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", Flags);

    /// <summary>
    /// A little hack to determine the number of parameters that we
    /// need to pass to the SaveMethod.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly bool IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive = SendMethod.GetParameters().Length == 3;

    /// <summary>
    /// The raw contents of this MailMessage as a MemoryStream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The caller.</param>
    /// <returns>A MemoryStream with the raw contents of this MailMessage.</returns>
    public static MemoryStream RawMessage(this MailMessage self)
    {
        var result = new MemoryStream();

        var mailWriter = MailWriterConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { result });
        SendMethod.Invoke(self, Flags, null, IsRunningInDotNetFourPointFive ? new[] { mailWriter, true, true } : new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);
        result = new MemoryStream(result.ToArray());
        CloseMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, Flags, null, new object[] { }, null);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

> result = new MemoryStream(result.ToArray());

with:

> result = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.ToArray().ToString()));

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but this web be result in an exception "Memory stream is not expandable."